# EF Code first - database custom Initializer always giving excpetion - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm developing a web application with EF code first approach.
Everything seems to be working fine unitl I set the

```
<contexts>
      <context type="XYZ.LogDal.LogContext, XYZ.LogDal">
<databaseInitializer type="XYZ.Common.EntityFramework.DatabaseInitializer, XYZ.Common" />
 </context>
```

in the web.config, then I get these exceptions:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'XYZ.EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. The system could not find the file.":"XYZ.EntityFramework"}


{"Could not load type 'XYZ.Common.EntityFramework.DatabaseInitializer' from assembly 'XYZ.Common'.":"XYZ.Common.EntityFramework.DatabaseInitializer"}
```

The DBContext (LogContext) is in an assembly named XYZ.LogDal.

The initializer is in another assembly named: XYZ.Common, under namespace: XYZ.Common.EntityFramework

I don't want to set the initializer in code, like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseInitializer<LogContext>());
```

I want to do it in the web.config inwhich the framework should find this custom initializer and use it.

I rebuilt the projects and I updated the referenced assemblies. The access level for the classes is public and I did all what in other questions is recommended, but wihtout any luck...

It will be great if you can recommend me any solution

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, that you didn't specify generic parameter of your `DatabaseInitializer`. Try this instead:

```
<databaseInitializer type="XYZ.Common.EntityFramework.DatabaseInitializer`1[[XYZ.LogDal.LogContext, XYZ.LogDal]], XYZ.Common" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will test this and get back to you!